# Can FaceBook FB.ui method work for any website?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sharer

I am making a music player, each track will have a customized share button. I am using FB.ui method to have the customized button. However, it does not work correctly.

```
function myfb(){
FB.ui({
method: 'share',
  href: trackURL,
}, function(response){});
}
```

When I press the button it gives an error:

`Given URL is not permitted by the application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.`

I relised that I must enter a domain name in the app settings on FaceBook. But my app will be used by many users and on different domains. So what should I put there ?
Actually how can I make it working?

Here is the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/danials/zX7UJ/3/

Comment: You can not use the same app across multiple domains. Probably easiest if you don’t use the JS SDK at all, and the URL redirection version of the Share dialog instead: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog#redirect

Comment: @CBroe Thanks for your post. What do you mean by JS SDK? I am really new in FaceBook API. So should I use the FB SDK to make it happen? And about the redirection, it seems really good, but is it possible to make the popup windows when the button is pressed. I tried it but it opens a new tab.

Comment: The JS SDK is the JS library FB provides – that amongst other things contains the `FB` object that you are already using, and that you could not use without the SDK. And no, I’m saying the opposite of what you read into it – _don’t_ use the SDK, because you can not do that across different domains. And how to open a simple link in a popup window … well that you should be able to find out yourself.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks for your help. Things are clearer now. for popup I think I must have `&display=popup` in the url.

Comment: @DanielJJ, just for the records, I couldn't catch, you removed your question, I created an example that use the Sharer instead of "Share Dialog" http://codepen.io/adamazad/pen/udcym, sorry for being late.

Comment: @AdamAzad Wow Thank you so much. U did a great work. Actually, as I didn't get any respond so I thought maybe my question is off topic so I removed it. But finally I found a similar solution as you did. Can you post it here as an answer so I can choose ?!